# Cannot sign in user to Firebase in Android app

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I entered correct email address and password in "owners" object. run time error comes this :

> E/RecaptchaCallWrapper: Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=custom_signInWithPassword)with exception - There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.

After login, I want to go to profile page.

This is my login.java

```
public class owner_login extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText textEmail, textPswd;
    Button buttonSignupOwner, buttonLogin;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_owner_login);
        FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
        FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).setUserProperty("debug", "true");
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("owners");
        textEmail = findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        textPswd = findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        buttonLogin = findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = textEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = textPswd.getText().toString().trim();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    textEmail.setError("Email is required");
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    textPswd.setError("Password is required");
                    return;
                }
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < AuthResult > () {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task\ < AuthResult\ > task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            String userId = user.getUid();
                            mDatabase.child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                    String username = snapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
                                    String email = snapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(owner_login.this, owners_Profile.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("username", username);
                                    intent.putExtra("email", email);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                                    Toast.makeText(owner_login.this, "Failed to retrieve user information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(owner_login.this, "Authentication failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message is quite explicit: there is no user in the project with the email address you entered. This means that you'll have to call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` to create that user first, before you can sign in with `signInWithEmailAndPassword`.

To prevent getting this error, you may want to [call `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(java.lang.String)) with just the email address - to see if Firebase has a email/password account for the email address the user enteres.

Answer (score 0):

try running $(flutterfire configure) in terminal and make sure that you have enabled email/password in
firebase-> authentication -> sign-in template.

hope will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I solved it by clearing the Android studio cache: File -> Invalidate Caches. After that everything worked.